# Import large data from excel onto DataGridView and save into Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, datagridview

I have around 12 thousands data on excel , i need to import on to DataGridView and then save it to SQL Server database.

The problem i am facing with breaking excel data into group of 1000 data, and saving it to database is for obvious is that, UI Freezes. Now i can't even imagine to import all 12 thousand data at once, God save me then !

How can i achieve this task without freezing problem ? I tried searching and found out about DataGridView virtualmode property. How can i implement this properly , help me to find right direction.

Comment: Have you tried using BackgroundWorker? it will help your UI to stay responsive. [Have a look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @SDP, It would be better if you use threading for it.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid   I will look into it, thank you :)

Comment: why are you importing rows into grid? can you use paging?

Comment: @FLICKER i just need to save the data onto database, displaying it in DGV is just for viewing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

' LIBRARIES

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

' LOAD DATA GRID VIEW

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim sql As String

    connectionString = "data source=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
    "initial catalog=NORTHWIND;Trusted_Connection=True"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    cnn.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders"
    Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    dscmd.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    cnn.Close()

End Sub
```

' FROM DATA GRID VIEW TO SQL SERVER

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim headers = (From header As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() Select header.HeaderText).ToArray
    Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Where Not row.IsNewRow Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
    Dim str As String = ""
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\OrdersTest.csv")
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headers))
        'sw.WriteLine(String.Join(","))
        For Each r In rows
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
        Next
        sw.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

I don't understand why the loading process would cause your machine to freeze.  i have never encountered this problem before.

If you want a really quick way to load data to SQL Server, just use Bulk Insert and get rid of the whole Data Grid View thing.

```
BULK INSERT EmployeeDB.dbo.Employees
FROM 'C:\Data\EmployeeData_c.dat'
WITH 
  (
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
  );
```

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/bulk-inserts-via-tsql-in-sql-server/